# Dynamic partial view list not being picked up when saving

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view that gets rendered in my main view using this code

```
<div>
    <h3>Budget Detail</h3>
    <div><input type="button" id="addbudgetdetail" value="Add row" /></div>
    <div id="new-budgetdetail">
        @if (Model.budget != null)
        {
            foreach (var budgetdetail in Model.budget.budgetdetails)
            {
                @Html.Partial("budgetdetail", Model)
            }
        }
        else 
        { 
            @Html.Partial("budgetdetail", Model)

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a java script to dynamically add more partial views when clicking a button

```
$(function () {
    $('#addbudgetdetail').on('click', function () {
        jQuery.get('@Url.Action("budgetdetail")').done(function (html) {
            $('#new-budgetdetail').append(html);
            $('form').data('validator', null);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
        });
    });
});
```

This is My partial view:

```
@model BudgetPortalMVC4.Models.NewBudgetModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem(""))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
    <div class="item">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.CategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedCategory" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory, Model.SubCategoriesList, "Please select", new { @class =  "SelectedSubCategory" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubCategory)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.budgetdetail.Amount)              
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.budgetdetail.Amount)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.budgetdetail.Amount)
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" id="deleteRow" class="deleteRow">Delete</a</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

My problem is when I click submit I don't see any list for my partial views.
I can only see the data that is coming directly from my main view.

Am I missing an IEnumerable property somewhere? Should I try to use editor templates instead?

Comment: You cannot use an `EditorTemplate` with `BeginCollectionItem()`. And remove the scripts from your partails. You `foreach` loop makes no sense - I assume its meant to be `@Html.Partial("budgetdetail", budgetdetail)` but the `else` would throw an exception if it got that far

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I had to rework the models and instead of using a big model grouping the budget and budget detail, i am using 2 models one for budget and one for budgetdetail.

I also rewrote the dropdown lists to comply to the new model:

```
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.category)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idCategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoriesList, "idCategory", "CategoryName"), "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedCategory" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.idCategory)


  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.subcategory)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idSubcategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubCategoriesList, "Value", "Text"), "Please select", new { @class = "SelectedSubCategory" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.idSubcategory)
```

Instead of using a partial view I created an editor template. Following Stephen's advice that BeginCollection can't be use in editor templates I used an html helper to create unique items in my collection.

This is the code for the helper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace BudgetPortalMVC4.Extensions
{

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EditorForMany<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TValue>>> expression, string htmlFieldName = null) where TModel : class
    {
        var items = expression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlFieldName))
        {
            var prefix = html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;

            htmlFieldName = (prefix.Length > 0 ? (prefix + ".") : String.Empty) + ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var dummy = new { Item = item };
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var memberExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(dummy), dummy.GetType().GetProperty("Item"));
            var singleItemExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TValue>>(memberExp, expression.Parameters);

            sb.Append(String.Format(@"<input type=""hidden"" name=""{0}.Index"" value=""{1}"" />", htmlFieldName, guid));
            sb.Append(html.EditorFor(singleItemExp, null, String.Format("{0}[{1}]", htmlFieldName, guid)));

        }

        return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
    }
 }
}
```

Now I call the template from the main using an intermediate IEnumerable view.

This is the call from the main view:

```
@Html.EditorForMany(x => x.budgetdetails)
```

And this is the intermediate IEnumerable view:

```
  @model IEnumerable<BudgetPortalMVC4.Models.budgetdetail>

 @{
Layout = null;
  }

  @Html.EditorForMany(x => x, "budgetdetails")
```

Hope this is helpful.